# Cannot find message_id in the notification_open events. But I got it in the firebase_messaging.data table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I need to analyze the notification data stored in BigQuery.

`<project_name>.analytics_[0-9]*.event_*` This table contains an event with the name notification_open, but the event_params are empty and there is no message_id.

In this documentation, https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en, we can see Google Analytics will log (message_name, message_time, message_device_time, message_id, topic, label, and message_channel).

Can you assist me if I need to configure anything on the mobile side, as well as Google Analytics or Firebase?

```
SELECT * FROM `<project_name>.analytics_[0-9]*.events_*`, unnest(event_params) as event_param where event_name = 'notification_open' and event_param.key = 'message_id' LIMIT 1000
```

BigQuery: There is no data to display.

I expect to find data to analyze it.